# Divs being pushed down when windows is made smaller

Tags: html, css

Pretty new to html and css and i'm just having the problem described in the title. My nav is pushing down div with the id main.

```
nav{
width:120px;
float:left;
margin:0px 5px 0px 5px; 

#main{
display:inline-block;
padding: 1em;
float:left;
position:relative;
min-width: 900px;
```

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

edit:

Hi guys, maybe i should explain it better. On the page there is a nav to the left and a div to the right of it. When the windows width is made smaller the div to the right is being pushed below the nav instead of stay where it is and it's content being displayed off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have explicitly told your element to behave like that. When you set `min-width` and a width in pixels, you are telling your elements to stay the same size no matter what happens. Remove `min-width` and set width to a percentage value like `1%` instead of `50px` like this:

```css
nav {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  float:left;
}
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background: black;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that's making my main overlap the nav.

Comment: @Peter use `z-index` for that. have a look at the example above

Comment: Hi guys, maybe i should explain it better. On the page there is a nav to the left and a div to the right of it. When the windows width is made smaller the div to the right is being pushed below the nav instead of stay where it is and it's content being displayed off the screen.

Comment: @Peter you have **explicitly** told your element to behave like that. when you set `min-width` and a width in pixels, you are telling your elements to stay the same size **no matter what happens**. remove `min-width` and set width to a percentage value like `1%` instead of `50px`

Comment: Hi, thanks that seems to have fixed it :) just I also have a 3 articles inside that main div and they are having the same problem. I set the width to % for them too and it's still the same.